# map kit annotation button not working in (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, button, swift3, mapkit

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/19/3/annotations-and-accessory-views-mkpinannotationview. I can not gut the annotation to display the information button. I do not know if I have to put something in the storyboard.

[image: Here is a picture of the storyboard with the button selected].

Anyway so the button is not displaying in the annotation. Just the cities name. Below is my code. Picture of missing button:

[image: missing button]

```
    import MapKit
import UIKit

class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var title: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var info: String

init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.info = info
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)


@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")

    mapView.addAnnotations([london])
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // 1
    let identifier = "Capital"

    // 2
    if annotation is Capital {
        // 3
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            //4
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

            // 5
            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        } else {
            // 6
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return annotationView
    }

    // 7
    return nil
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let capital = view.annotation as! Capital
    let placeName = capital.title
    let placeInfo = capital.info

    let ac = UIAlertController(title: placeName, message: placeInfo, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    present(ac, animated: true)
}}
```

Comment: try moving button to front of map view

Comment: @vindoh what do you mean by that put it. In the view did load function.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the "missing button"?

Comment: @muescha just edited the question.

Comment: the button should be a Button with an (i) and you see that (i) below ireland :) - so the problem is - the button is there but on the wrong place

Comment: @RamitJudo judo by outlet of UIbutton make it move to front of map view `self.mapview bringsubviewtofront(self.button)`